How to make top part of list background stay fixed?
How do I make the top part of the list background to stay fixed?
For example, here, the upper part of the list background (the light grey) should not slide up. In other words, the list background should only be allowed to move towards the bottom of the screen.

import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Attendance: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct AttendanceRow: View {
    var attendance: Attendance
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(attendance.name)
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 20)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let attendances = [
        Attendance(name: "John"),
        Attendance(name: "Michael"),
        Attendance(name: "Steve"),
        Attendance(name: "Donald"),
        Attendance(name: "Johathan"),
        Attendance(name: "William"),
        Attendance(name: "Dave"),
        Attendance(name: "Richard"),
        Attendance(name: "Boris"),
        Attendance(name: "Catherine"),
        Attendance(name: "Susan")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(attendances) { attendance in
                        AttendanceRow(attendance: attendance)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


So do you want to only move contents inside of it? Did i understand it right?

Yes, I don't want the light grey to go beyond the top part of the screen.

Get rid of the List and add a background to the vstack

If you are just trying to remove the space above the list then this answer to Remove top padding from List might help. Then:

To prevent the list from scrolling through the safe area at the top of the screen, add nominal top padding of 1. This breaks the contact with the safe area edge.
To fill the rest of the screen with the same background as the list surround, apply UIColor.systemGroupedBackground as background to the VStack.

NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(attendances) { attendance in
                    AttendanceRow(attendance: attendance)
                }
            } header: {
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0)
        .padding(.top, 1)
    }
    .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
}



EDIT2 Following from your comments, one way to have the corners remain fixed and round is to "glue on" rounded corners as an overlay. If the color is matched to the background color then they are only seen when the list is scrolled up, the rest of the time they just merge into the background.
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(attendances) { attendance in
                    AttendanceRow(attendance: attendance)
                }
            } header: {
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0)
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill()
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
                .compositingGroup()
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .padding(.top, 1)
    }
    .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
}

[

Great, this produces the desired effect. Just one thing is missing, the list's corners should be rounded always.

(The corners should remain rounded)

Thank you for your time, but I want the list to behave as before, but with rounded corners.
Current behaviour: https://s4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-2dab8301b7.gif
Requested behaviour (but with rounded corners): https://s3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-bb05a0fbac.gif

Your image links are expired @Adventure

@Radioactive Here are the working links. Current behaviour: https://imgur.com/dckAPKT Requested behaviour (but with rounded corners always): https://imgur.com/TE4AwWj

@Adventure So if I understand correctly: when you pull the list down from the top, the background (with rounded corners) should appear to be attached to the rows and should move down with the rows. But when you scroll up, the background should appear to be detached from the rows and should stay fixed in place. Same goes for the bottom edge (in reverse). Correct?

Here's an edited GIF that shows exactly what I need, I tried my best to make it clear: https://i.imgur.com/lZVPin2.gif

"when you pull the list down from the top, the background (with rounded corners) should appear to be attached to the rows and should move down with the rows. But when you scroll up, the background should appear to be detached from the rows and should stay fixed in place." Yes, for the top edge. The bottom edge's default behaviour is fine, like in the edited GIF.

@Adventure OK answer updated again. Change the background color (in the overlay) to something like Color.orange, to see what's going on.
